# PHP how to prevent preg_match from being out of memory?

Tags: php, loops, segmentation-fault, preg-match, pcre

I wrote a web app which goes through some html pages using multi_curl.
Then I have to loop on my results array to search for specific entities with preg_match.

I do something like

```
foreach($tab as $user => $html_source)
{
   preg_match ($pattern , $html_source, $matches).
}
```

But for some reason, when my $pattern is not present and when $html_source is big enough I have this error in console :

> Zsh : gsegmentation fault

( or error 500 in browser but my script is a cronjob so it was just to check what happend)

---

I tried to use

> ini_set("pcre.recursion_limit", "1048");

or any bigger value, but it doesn't help.

---

So my first problem is not that preg_match crashes but it is that my loop crashes. I need to continue to loop on the remaining results.

Does anybody have a solution to continue to loop even if I have this error ? 
Else Does anybody have a solution not to have this error ?

Thank you. Cheers.

Comment: Hello. Pattern doesn't change anything. The case is that when the pattern is not found in a big source code ($html_source)

Comment: Nobody has an idea here?